# Safari - the "reader" function, only shows 1 article

Tags: html

I just noticed that on my blog, which is html5 coded, the "reader" in iPhone/iPod only shows the first "article". Each blog is wrapped in an article-tag. Does anyone have any info on this? Is it any guidelines on how to do this? My blog address is "storkas" - dot com.

Comment: What do you mean by "reader"? I just tried viewing your blog from mobile Safari and I seem to be able to view all your articles.

Comment: When you are on the blog, you can see it says "reader" just beside the "reload webpage" icon, in the address bar. You can click on "reader", and then you'll see what i mean.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I wasn't aware of the feature - learned something new today. I did some digging around and found [this link](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/safari-reader). I'm not familiar with the Safari Reader so I probably won't be of much help (I don't see anything immediately wrong with your markup). That being said, perhaps you can set up a duplicate test page to try out some changes based on the information from the link (e.g. add more text to other articles and see if they show up). Good luck!

Comment: Allright! Thanks for the link. I'll try to find the solution to this, and then I'll post it here. Thanks for the effort though :)